# HAProxy APIs - Reload Config

Tags: haproxy

I notice there are two APIs for HaProxy.  DataPlane and Runtime.

I don't see anything obvious that will just tell the system to reload and parse the .cfg file.

Seems like a no brainer thing to want to do.  I have a lets encrypt container running in docker and I want to just, via https, or some mechanism tell HaProxy to reload the ssl certs or in general load up a changed .cfg file.

I'm aware of the individual SSL reload commands, which will implement if no other good solutions.  Also of course I could extend the haproxy container to add some kind of custom api to kick it.

Ps.  I don't have enough traffic to warrant the zero packet loss yelp solution  ;-)

Comment: Ok, it seems the dataplane api has the ability to push a new config file ?   I take it that Enterprise only ?  and requiring money.

Answer (score 3):

There is a so-called [Master CLI socket](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.0/management.html#9.4) that allows initiating a reload.

```
echo "reload" | socat /var/run/haproxy-master.sock
```

This socket can be configured to listen on a TCP port

```
 haproxy -W -S 127.0.0.1:1234
```

It is available in the non-commercial version.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sounds perfect, I will give it a go.

Comment: I have now tried this.  It gives zero feedback. Also, the certs do not get picked up.  Any ideas ??    If I send "help" it talks about sending a command to @master ... should I be doing that ?".  There are also levels, user and admin, which one should I use.

Answer (score 0):

[DataplaneAPI](https://github.com/haproxytech/dataplaneapi) is available also for the open-source HAProxy. It requires setting proper permission to the admin socket, in `haproxy.cfg`:

```
global 
    master-worker  # in order to run dataplane api
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock level admin mode 660

 program api
  command dataplaneapi -f /etc/haproxy/dataplaneapi.yml
```

`dataplaneapi` is a golang API server that communicates with HAProxy via Unix socket. Committing transaction via the API will trigger `haproxy` reload. See [documentation for more details](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/dataplaneapi/community/#put-/services/haproxy/configuration/global).

While you can use the `dataplaneapi` to perform safe HAProxy reload (which will execute reload via admin Unix socket), you can still use the "oldschool" method:

```
  service haproxy reload
  # or 
  systemctl reload haproxy
```

this would validate the config file:

```
 haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -c
```

and then reload `haproxy` process using `SIGUSR2`

```
 kill -USR2 $MAINPID
```

or you could reload `haproxy` service using the `haproxy-master.sock`, e.g.:

```
socat /run/haproxy-master.sock - <<< "reload"
```